# Array saving as blank in MongoDB database from React Axios post

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

I have the following Schema (with some options taken out for simplicity):

```
const SubmitDebtSchema = new Schema ({
  balance: [{
    balanceDate: Date,
    newBalance: Number
  }]
});
```

And I have the following serverless function which posts the Schema to my database:

```
module.exports = async (req, res) => {

  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

  await SubmitDebt.create(req.body)
  .then(() => {
    res.send(JSON.stringify({ success: true }));
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
    res.send(JSON.stringify({ success: false }));
  });

};
```

To post to my database, I have the following Axios post call:

```
  onSubmit = async (e) => {

    e.preventDefault();

    const balanceDate = new Date();

    await axios.post("/api/submit/submitDebt", {
      balanceDate: balanceDate,
      newBalance: this.state.balance,
    })

    this.props.history.push('/dashboard');
  }
```

However, every time I submit the request, it just returns an empty array. The 'balance' array gets put into my database, but there's never anything in it. It just saves like this:

[image: Empty MongoDB array]

Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong here, and why my database entries aren't saving in my  array?

It's worth pointing out - the rest of the call works fine! The entry is saved, it's just the array which is the problem.

Comment: Should the balance hold an object or an array of objects?

Comment: An array of objects. :-)

Comment: okay, what is `SubmitDebt`?

Comment: also when should a new object be added to the balance array and when should a new item be added to the collection?

Comment: SubmitDebt is how the SubmitDebtSchema is imported in to my serverless function file. And at the moment, this function is just designed to create a new item for the collection. A new balance array will be done via update afterwards in a separate function.

Comment: okay, then you should change the req.body either in the frontend or in the serverless function to match the schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try modifying the function this way to match your schema:

```
module.exports = async (req, res) => {

  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  const submitDebt = {
   balance: [{...req.body}] // it might be better to first extract what you need and use it here.
  };

  await SubmitDebt.create(submitDebt)
  .then(() => {
    res.send(JSON.stringify({ success: true }));
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
    res.send(JSON.stringify({ success: false }));
  });

};
```

I also noticed that you're using both `await` and `.then`, either one of them is enough.

```
module.exports = async (req, res) => {
    
      res.statusCode = 200;
      res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
      
      const { balanceDate, newBalance } = req.body;
      const submitDebt = {
       balance: [{balanceDate, newBalance}]
      };
      try {
       await SubmitDebt.create(submitDebt)
       res.send(JSON.stringify({ success: true }));
      } catch(err) {
       console.log(err);
       res.send(JSON.stringify({ success: false }));
      }
    };
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I've got it working now by adjusting the Axios post to reflect the object. So balance -> newBalance, balanceDate. But this would also work too, so accepting! Thanks for the help.

Comment: @JonNicholson Great! also note that you don't need both `await` and `.then` see my second snippet.